# Kogito processes build failing - enum mismatch

Tags: quarkus, kogito

Using Quarkus version 2.7.3.Final, the build is failing because of the 2 different enums value field clashing.

Java 11

Error details:

Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step org.kie.kogito.quarkus.processes.deployment.ProcessesAssetsProcessor#postGenerationProcessing threw an exception: org.infinispan.protostream.DescriptorParserException: Enum value org.kie.kogito.app.Level.value clashes with enum value org.kie.kogito.app.Error422Code.value

Is it a known issue?
Is there any workaround to use the enums?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are multiple enum classes, and each class has the value field to handle and return the enum value. On checking the unique name, it is complaining that two different value clashes. These two enums are having different values, but they have the value field

Answer (score 0):

I managed to easily reproduce the issue and created the following JIRA to track: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-7063

Comment: This issue is not just for the Enum with same values, but if any two enums having the same name field, ex. private String value;

Comment: Thanks Cristiano. In my case, the enum values are different, but each enum has the value field, that holds the value of enum. That's where I'm facing the issue. Can you please make sure the JIRA bug you created also include it as well. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-7063

Comment: Cristiano - Is there any time frame when the fix will be avaliable?

Comment: Hi Cristiano - I see there is an update on the  JIRA to track: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-7063. But the problem hasn't been solved. With setting the property kogito.persistence.proto.marshaller=false, the following error get started coming:  Caused by: org.kie.kogito.serialization.process.ProcessInstanceMarshallerException: 
Unexpected error while trying to read object
        at org.kie.kogito.serialization.process.impl.marshallers.ProtobufObjectMarshallerStrategy.readObject(ProtobufObjectMarshallerS
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.testme.Myclass

Comment: @user18783790 that still not available yet, Kogito version 1.23.0 will include the complete fix.